# jQuery Validation: If one input is entered, others should become mandatory

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with several lines of 4 input fields, it looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="company01" id="company01" /></td>
    <td><input name="description01" id="description01" /></td>
    <td><input name="costs01" id="costs01" class="sum" /></td>
    <td><input name="file01" id="file01" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input name="company02" id="company02" /></td>
    <td><input name="description02" id="description02" /></td>
    <td><input name="costs02" class="sum" id="costs02" /></td>
    <td><input name="file02" id="file02" /></td>
</tr>
```

Now, when the user enters one of the inputs of the row (for example the costs field), it should be mandatory to enter the company and the descripton (but not the attachment).

File-Upload is never mandatory. However, the user has to complete at least on row with company, description and costs.

Could someone tell me how I can check if at least one row has been completed? And how would I go about checking if the other 2 have been completed using jQUery Validation Plugin?

Comment: Certainly something you'd want -conditionally required fields. In this case, though... why not add the subsequent rows on request and _always_ require those fields for all rows?

Comment: Please show your attempt at a solution to this.  If you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, where is your `.validate()` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't solve it with the validate method. What I did was, checking all inputs within a row to see if they are all empty or all filled out. If any row doesn't match, I just create an alert dialog.

Not really nice, but at least it gets the validation done.

Answer (score 3):

can be done with **required** method and [dependency expressions](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression)

```
....
rules : {
  company01 : { required : "#company02:blank" },
  description01 : { required : "#company01:filled" },
  costs01: { required : "#company01:filled" },
  // now company 2 
  company02 : { required : "#company01:blank" },
  description02 : { required : "#company02:filled" },
  costs02: { required : "#company02:filled" }
}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ["dependency-expression"](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) to make the rule for one field depend on the state of another.

Here is a working example...

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/GMK5V/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // other options,
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: '#field1:filled'
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML** (also added an `id` to each `input`):

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, jQuery validate won't check disabled inputs. While the dependency expressions do exactly what you ask for in the question, I think it's worth asking yourself if your form makes sense to allow a description without a company name. Depending on the user experience you want to go for, it might be better to start with the description, costs and file upload disabled, clearly communicating to the user that those fields are not usable on their own. Then you mark them as required in your jQuery validate rules and when they're enabled, they're required.

The trick is then to make them enabled when the company name is added. I would do this like the following:

**Markup**

```
<!-- add a class to the row for ease of dom traversal -->
<tr class="company-row">
    <!-- add a class to the company name for ease of selection -->
    <td><input class="company-name" name="company01" id="company01" /></td>
    <td><input name="description01" id="description01" /></td>
    <td><input name="costs01" id="costs01" class="sum" /></td>
    <td><input name="file01" id="file01" /></td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.company-name').on('keyup', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val() != '') {
            $this.parents('.company-row').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $this.parents('.company-row').find('input').not('.company-name').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
)}
```

That should do the trick, but admittedly I've not tested anything I just wrote. You'll also probably run into the situation where someone has left off a company description, tried to submit, been given the validation message for the field, deletes the company name and the validation message won't go away (and they might not be able to submit the form). I forget how to fix that one just now, but the blanket approach is to call `.resetform()` on the whole validator, which would remove any validation messages. That might work if you call it on the submit.